# How can I notify the containing Window that a certain UserControl it contains invoked an ICommand/RelayCommand/DelegateCommand?

Tags: wpf, icommand, routed-events, routed-commands, delegatecommand

### TL/DR:

How can I notify the containing `Window` that a certain `UserControl` it contains invoked an `ICommand`/`RelayCommand`/`DelegateCommand` ?

I want to respond the `CanExecuteChanged` events in the `Window`.

### Expansion:

The `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CarProject.CarUserControl" ... >
    <!-- lots of stuff here... -->
        <Button Name="FuelCar" Command="{Binding FuelCarCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding FuelType}" >
            Start fueling the car...
        </Button>
    <!-- lots of stuff here... -->
</UserControl>
```

The `Window`:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:carProject="clr-namespace:CarUserControl;assembly=CarUserControl"
        ...
        >
    <!-- lots of stuff here... -->
        <carProject:CarUserControl Name="TheCar"/>
    <!-- lots of stuff here... -->
</Window>
```

Whenever the button `FuelCar` is clicked, a custom command, `FuelCarCommand` is `Execute`d. (what should be the right type for `FuelCarCommand`? simple `ICommand` implementation? a `RelayCommand` subtype or a `DelegateCommand`? or maybe simply `Routed Events` and that's it... ?).

That command does some business-logic stuff, and while it works (it takes time to fuel the car), other controls in the `CarUserControl` are disabled.

But I also need the `Window` to disable some controls that are not directly related to `CarUserControl` (e.g. `FuelStationNumberOne` should be disabled since it's occupied by the `CarUserControl`).

What is the right way to accomplish that? do commands are the right mean here?

Comment: Can you expand your post with an example? It's hard to understand what you exactly need.

Comment: @nvoigt - I expanded the question

Comment: If your window knows nothing about the user control, the user control could feature a bindable bool that indicates it's busy. Your window can bind to it and react accordingly.

Comment: @nvoigt, there's no way to bubble up the information like with routed events, but using the commands mechanism?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Yes, you can use routed events. For example raise one. You can raise one whenever you feel like it, I'm not sure how this would conflict with your commands?

Comment: I can't raise routed event from a command (the command currently implements an `ICommand`, so it does the work of "fueling" by itself - the functionality is located within that command), since it's not a `UIElement`. I can pass the `UIElement` object (i.e. the `CarUserControl` object) to it somehow, but that would result in spaghetti-code...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68892/discussion-between-tal-and-nvoigt).